# Using replace filter mangles jekyll site.tags

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm having a problem controlling the appearance of my site's tags when using a for loop to render out all `tags` in `site.tags`.

This is what I am intending:

```
<li class="sliced-almonds">sliced almonds</li>
```

And this is what I have:

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
    <li class="{{ tag | handleize | replace:' ','-' }}">{{ tag }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But instead I get this:

```
<li class="[" sliced-almonds",-[<post:-="" salads="" salad-04="">]]"&gt;sliced almonds</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured it out. When using grabbing tags from `site.tags`, `tag[0]` is the name and `tag[1]` are all of the posts associated with that tag.

```
<ul>
    {% for tag in site.tags %}
    <li class="{{ tag[0]  | replace:' ','-' }}">{{ tag }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```